# Centralizar uma div dentro de outra div 100%

Tags: css

Eu tenho uma `div` que tá 100% e tem uma imagem de background.

```
.bannerTotalHome {
    background: url("../imagens/bannerTotalHome.jpg") no-repeat center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 570px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

E dentro haverá uma outra `div` que terá uma imagem de background.

```
.logoHome {
    background: url("../imagens/logoHanka.png") no-repeat center;
    width: 285px;
    height: 152px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -142.5px;
}
```

O que acontece, é que eu centralizei o logo usando `position`, eu não sei se essa é a forma mais correta, ou se há uma forma mais fácil para fazer isso?

O meu HTML está assim:

```
<div class="bannerTotalHome p-relative">
    <div class="logoHome margin-top-110"></div>
    <div class="margin-top-375 d-block">
        <h2>SUA MELHOR ESCOLHA EM</h2>
        <h1>COMPONENTES AUTOMOTIVOS</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nesse caso, se eu usar um `margin-top` dentro dessa div `bannerTotalHome` ele vai jogar a div bem pra baixo. Por isso pergunto se o correto para centralizar aquela div dentro da outra é da forma que eu fiz.

Comment: Já tentou com margin: 0 auto; ?

Comment: Você quer centralizar horizontalmente ou verticalmente?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Horizontalmente

Comment: @FelipeStoker Então `margin: 0 auto;` é a melhor alternativa mesmo.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft eu usei agora `margin: 110px auto 0 auto;` só que ele joga a div de cima pra baixo também, isso que eu não queria, tá certo? por isso usei `position`

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft [Crie um Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) com seu código. Fiz um teste aqui mas sem suas imagens não consegui visualizar o problema.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Criei um de exemplo, usando imagens aleatórias da internet para simular;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algumas modificações em seu código usando imagens da internet para simular e acredito que seja isso que você precisaria... caso não, por favor avise!

Adicionei `margin: 0 auto;` em sua class `.logoHome`

Como André Ribeiro observou, substitui o `position: absolute e margin-top:110px;` por `padding-top: 110px;`

Veja o exemplo:

> http://jsfiddle.net/rafaelwithoeft/u7z38no2/2/

Comment: `position: absolute` e `margin-top: 110px` podem ser substituídos por um simples `padding-top: 110px` em `.logoHome`. Só não tenho certeza se é essa a intenção do autor da pergunta.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Concordo. Ele pode modificar até encontrar o que melhor se encaixa para ele.

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais fácil e simples é utilizando `margin: 0 auto`. Basta que sua `div` pai tenha uma largura definida.

```css
.a {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%
}

.b {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto
}


/* somente para melhorar a visualização do exemplo */
.a{ background: #27ae60 }
.b{ background: #2ecc71; height: 100% }
```

```html
<div class='a'>
    <div class='b'></div>
</div>
```

Uma alternativa, aproveitando que a sua div filha possui posição `absolute` é centralizá-la por meio das regras `left` e `right`. Por exemplo, colocando-a 10% em relação a direita e a esquerda:

```css
.a {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%
}

.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%; right: 10%;
}

/* somente para melhorar a visualização do exemplo */
.a{ background: #c0392b }
.b{ background: #e74c3c; top: 0; bottom: 0 }
```

```html
<div class='a'>
    <div class='b'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá amigo fiz um exemplo abaixo que você pode conferir no link http://jsfiddle.net/p16kLwhz/

```
<div class="a">
        <div class="b">
            <img src="https://www.cardvantagens.com.br/static/img/home/versao_dois/logo.png">
        </div>
    </div>

    .a{
       float:left;
       background: #CCC;
       width: 100%;
       height: 570px;
    }
     .b{
         width: 35%;
        margin: 0 auto;
     }
    .b img{
        width: 294px;
        height: 75px;
        margin-top: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
```